# Tomcat's accept count

Tags: java, tomcat, networking, tcp

I have the following question on Tomcat's `acceptCount`.
It says:

> The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all
>   possible request processing threads are in use. Any requests received
>   when the queue is full will be refused. The default value is 10.

I am not sure how this works. I mean I know that there is a separate TCP queue that determines how many connections can come so if I put `acceptCount` in application level e.g. 30000, does it make any difference?
I mean it seems that this configuration is not useful.

Am I right?

Comment: in tomcat 7 the default value is 100: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a direct pass-through to the `backlog` parameter of [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int,%20int%29)'s constructor. The idea is that the OS can hold onto incoming connections even if they can't be processed right away. It's only useful if you have bursty traffic and fast processing times.

Comment: But does it make any sense to put a huge number?Is this number limited by OS?

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov:What are the max in Windows and Linux?

Comment: On Linux the default is 128, but you can change it with `/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn`. Have no idea about Windows.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov:Does it make sense to increase that in OS?Or is it a bad idea?

Comment: Do you have a problem? Do your clients time out trying to connect? If so, maybe bumping that limit could help, but I'd try to improve the server side so it processes these new connections quicker.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov:I am trying to figure out how the best configuration is.

Comment: Then don't worry about it for now. The defaults are usually reasonable.

Comment: The best configuration is the default, until you find some reason to change it.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz:Why the best is the default?Is there a document specifying how the default configuration was determined as approapriate?

Comment: @Jim Default is best if you don't know what you are doing. Given that the original question was clearly written by someone who didn't know what they were doing, I recommended the default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it really can help. I've seen some java application with rather big trafic (tens of megabits per second). In some moment application responses became very sluggish and after some researching I've decided to increase the acceptcount parameter in server.xml. And it really helped, the problem went away.