# Explanation maxQueueSize in tomcat executor

Tags: tomcat, threadpoolexecutor

Please clarify the meaning of the parameter `maxQueueSize` in tomcat executor.

An additional question - whether it is linked to `acceptCount` in tomcat connector?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=tomcat+connector+executor+maxqueuesize

Answer (score 2):

This is very well mentioned [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)

> Each incoming request requires a thread for the duration of that
>   request. If more simultaneous requests are received than can be
>   handled by the currently available request processing threads,
>   additional threads will be created up to the configured maximum (the
>   value of the **maxThreads** attribute). If still more simultaneous
>   requests are received, they are stacked up inside the server socket
>   created by the Connector, up to the configured maximum (the value of
>   the **acceptCount** attribute). Any further simultaneous requests will
>   receive "connection refused" errors, until resources are available to
>   process them.

maxQueueSize : -The maximum number of runnable tasks that can queue up awaiting execution before we reject them. Default value is Integer.MAX_VALUE

The parameter **acceptCount** is related to the TCP queue. In this queue the OS can hold up certain number of connections even though they cannot be processed immediately. This concept is OS specific - for Linux you can understand this by referring [here](http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html) and some more insights are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903154/tomcats-accept-count).

**maxQueueSize** is the queue holding the actual request processing tasks which can be run by *atmost* maxThreads number of threads. They are actually in the queue for the very reason that the number of processing threads are limited and the task spends some time in queue before being picked up by Executor and assigned to a thread which is free to execute the task.